# if and else doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prova {
private static Scanner sc;
private static Scanner s;
private static Scanner ri;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Ciao, come ti chiami?");
    String value;
    s = new Scanner(System.in);
    value=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Oh, " + value + " è un nome fantastico. Adesso ciò che dovrai fare è sceliere un numero n (più piccolo lo prendi e più faceile ti risulterà il problema) ");
    int i;
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    i =sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println(i*i*4);
  System.out.println("Che relazione c'è tra il numero scelto da te e quello dato da me ?");
  String risposta;
  ri = new Scanner(System.in);
  risposta=ri.nextLine();
  if (risposta.equals("è il quadrato moltiplicato per 4")){
  System.out.println("Complimenti! + 10 punti");}
  else { System.out.println("Oh no, hai sbaliato! - 2 punto");}
  System.out.println("Passiamo alla prossima domanda. Chi è il presidente della Repubblica Italiana? (scrivere nome e cognome in questo ordine e tutto minuscolo)");
  String risposta1;
  ri = new Scanner(System.in);
  risposta1=ri.nextLine();
  if (risposta1.equals("sergio mattarella")){
      System.out.println("Complimenti! + 5 punti");}
  else {System.out.println("Oh no, hai sbagliato! - 1 punto");
  }
  if (risposta.equals("è il qaudrato moltiplicato per 4") & risposta1.equals("sergio mattarella") );
  System.out.println("hai ottwnuto 15 punti");// something does't work here ! how can i say it? do you understandt my question?
```

I need some help because it does't work very well, can you understand what i mean when i say there is a problem?

Comment: No, can you give us the problem/stacktrace?

Comment: *How* doesn't it work very well? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And remember that string comparisons are case-sensitive.

Comment: The code is very hard to understand , Can you please add some details

Comment: You need `&&` to combine your if conditions - not `&`

Comment: What is the code for , what is the expected Input and Output , What is your problem

Comment: The problem is the semicolon, not the single `&`.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (risposta.equals("è il qaudrato moltiplicato per 4") & 
risposta1.equals("sergio mattarella") );
  System.out.println("hai ottwnuto 15 punti");
```

This is causing your problem. Change it to:

```
if (risposta.equals("è il qaudrato moltiplicato per 4") &&     
    risposta1.equals("sergio mattarella")) {
  System.out.println("hai ottwnuto 15 punti");// something does't work here ! how can i say it? do you understandt my question?
}
```

- & should be &&
- You directly terminate your if(..) statement with a ;

Furthermore, read Some programmer dude's recommendations.